# java using jython has wrong python version

Tags: java, python, jython

Im trying to use java to run a python function through jython.jar. I'm using a python module that is downloaded from web which needs python 2.6 or higher. I'm pretty sure that my python is version 2.7.2. However, when I try to run the java program, it continues to report python 2.5 detected. How can I resolve this?

My code is:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ...
                //cmd
                String command = "\"xml\\" + name2 + "\"";
                PythonInterpreter python = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
                PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
                sys.path.append(new PyString("C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages"));
                python.execfile("work1.py");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):   File "work1.py", line 8, in <module>
    import networkx as nx   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\networkx\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    raise ImportError(m % sys.version_info[:2]) ImportError: Python version 2.6 or later is required for NetworkX (2.5 detected). Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Have you tried the obvious, namely, downloading the latest version of Jython and replacing your jython.jar? It sounds like you have an older version of Jython.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Jython 2.7b3, 2.7 beta adds language compatibility with CPython 2.7...
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.jython.devel/6145

2.7 beta 4 will come in July and after that a feature freeze. I suggest you join the python-dev mailing list to stay aware of new releases. Hope this helps

Comment: aissacf is correct. jython is alternative implementation of Python. It does not use the version of Python installed on the machine. aka. CPython. i.e. jython.jar IS python. You need the correct version.